# Change Text color Onfocus Event OR when user types something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having Form in which txt box already has some value which changes when some user clicks in inside the txt box.The Font color is slightly set to a light color. So when a user types something the Font Color Should change to a dark color and should remain dark. Is there any java script to do this.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.formWrapper input[type="text"]{float:left; width:178px; height:28px; line-height:27px; padding-left:5px; color:#CACACA; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="formWrapper">
<form name=form>
<Input type="text" name="name1"  value="Eg : Flat-27,Block 4,Skyline" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;" size="30">
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my example:

- on focus default text will be cleared and input element get green color
- on blur if input have no text it filled with default grey text

code:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
     if($(this).val() == this.defaultValue){$(this).val('');$(this).css("color","green");}
}).blur(function(){
     if($(this).val() == ''){$(this).val(this.defaultValue);$(this).css("color","grey");}
});
```

html:

```
<div class="formWrapper">
<form name=form>
<Input type="text" name="name1"  value="Eg : Flat-27,Block 4,Skyline" size="30">
</form>
</div>
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6rhFn/)

Comment: Yes, you need a jQuery libriary. You taged your question with jQuery tag.

Comment: Will You help Me how to use Jquery Library..your program not working on my localhost..plz help

Comment: you need to include it. Just put next line in your <head>...</head> block: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>

Comment: No Success, Can You post full program as another answer!!

Comment: please post That program on SO

Answer (score 0):

```
$("element").keydown(function() {
  this.value= "";
  $(this).css("color",darkcolorCode);
}).blur(function(){
    if( this.value == "default text" || $.trim(this.value) == "" ) {
       this.value == "default text";
        $(this).css("color",lightcolorCode);
    }
});
```